# Почему не работает функция?

Tags: javascript, функции

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Ступеньки </title>
<body bgcolor="yellow">
<script type="text/javascript">

function f(obj)
{
x=20*Math.random()
obj.s1.value=x
}
</script>
<form name="myform">
 <input type="text" name="s1" size=10  ><hr>
<input type=button name="b"value=" количество ступенек" 
onclick="f()">

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @niko, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: [В чем ошибка?](http://blog.hashcode.ru/2011/09/blog-post_24.html)

Answer (score 3):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function f(obj) { 
    var x = 20 * Math.random();
    obj.s1.value=x;
}
</script>

<form name="myform"> <input type="text" name="s1" size=10 >
<hr>
<input type=button name="b"value=" количество ступенек" onclick="f(this.form)">
</form>
```